# Creating map and use that within the MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am working on a migration project and the data needs to be migrated from system A to system B. The id's in system A and system B will be different. So maintaining a table with source and target column.

As part of the migration, For each record from source A, I need to go to the mapping table to find the corresponding target value. I am just trying avoid querying the mapping table for each query. Is there any way to store the mapping table as a key value map in a stored procedure and query the map as opposed to going to the table directly?

I was searching for collections in MySQL stored procedure, but didn't find anything.

**Database A:-**

**Table :** employee

```
---------------------------------
id    |  name  |       email     |
---------------------------------
10021 |  First1 | first@test.com |
---------------------------------
10035 |  First 2| first@test.com |
---------------------------------
```

**Database B:-**

**Table :** employee

```
---------------------------------
id    |  name  |       email     |
---------------------------------
1     |  First1 | first@test.com |
---------------------------------
2     |  First 2| first@test.com |
---------------------------------
```

**Table :** emp_mapping

```
----------------------
source_id | target_id|
----------------------
10021     |  1       | 
----------------------
10035     |  2       |
----------------------
```

**Stored Procedure for Migration**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadEmployees()
BEGIN
 DECLARE db1_empl_id INT;
 DECLARE db1_empl_name VARCHAR(20);
 DECLARE db1_empl_email VARCHAR(40);

 DECLARE db2_empl_id INT;

 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, name, email FROM db1.employees;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cursor_finished = 1;

 
 open cur;
    cur_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur INTO db1_empl_id, db1_empl_name, db1_empl_email;
                 
       IF cursor_finished = 1 THEN 
          LEAVE cur_loop;
       END IF;
       -- cursor loop statements
       
       -- I would like to move this to a map instead of querying for each record
       select target_id into db2_empl_id from db2.emp_mapping where source_id = db1_empl_id;
       
       insert into db2.employee(id,name,email) values(db2_empl_id, db1_empl_name, db1_empl_email);
       
       SET cursor_finished = 0; -- hence reset this value for cursor.
         
    end LOOP;
 close cur;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```